# Where does forever store console.log output?

Tags: node.js, forever

I installed forever and am using it, finding it quite funny.

But I realized that the logs are placed to somewhere else. Is there any tips?

Comment: if you just want to simply log the console.log result in the terminal directly use 
forever logs app.js -f 
This works pretty fine.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Forever takes command line options for output:

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

For example:

```
forever start -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js
```

See [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) for more info

Comment: what is the default path if I don't specify any parameters but just use like `forever myapp`? thanks!

Comment: I don't see it documented - I think it changed over time.  I see old logs in ~/.forever folder.  But I updated very recently and at least on my mac if I don't specify a log file name, it writes console.log to the terminal.

Comment: -a is also needed as an option if the files already exist. forever -a -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js

Comment: this gave me the output in the console and stopped the script when I stopped the output. using `forever start` with the same log parameters did what I wanted

Comment: What's the difference between LOGFILE and OUTFILE? For me it seems they contain exactly the same information!

Comment: @bryanmac I think you forgot to add "action" key in your example 
forever start -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js

Comment: @Dominic LOGFILE includes **all** output including output from the forever process, OUTFILE only includes stdout from your child script.

Comment: Note that the order is important.  I accidentally put -o out.log at the end (forever start my-script.js -o out.log), which definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 88):

Forever, by default, will put logs into a random file in `~/.forever/` folder.

You should run `forever list` to see the running processes and their corresponding log file.

Sample output

```
>>> forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command       script forever pid  logfile                         uptime
data:    [0] 6n71 /usr/bin/node app.js 2233    2239 /home/vagrant/.forever/6n71.log 0:0:0:1.590
```

However, it's probably best to specify with `-l` as mentioned by bryanmac.

Comment: Its not always a random file. If you specified a uid with the --uid flag when starting then it will create a log file using the specified uid.

Answer (score 23):

if you run the command "forever logs", you can see where are the logs files.

Source: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 13):

try the command

```
> forever logs
```

or

```
> sudo forever logs
```

you will get the log file's location

Answer (score 8):

It is a old question but i ran across the same issues. If you wanna see live output you can run

```
forever logs
```

This would show the path of the logs file as well as the number of the script. You can then use

```
forever logs 0 -f
```

0 should be replaced by the number of the script you wanna see the output for.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me :

```
forever -a -o out.log -e err.log app.js
```

Comment: What does the -a do?

Comment: @BrandonRos ` -a, --append `    Append logs; you can check for the rest of the options [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Answer (score 5):

Need to do normal
`forever start script.js`
to start, and to check console/error logs use
`forever logs`
this will print list of all logs being stored by forever
and then you can use `tail -f /path/to/logs/file.log` and this will print live logs to your window. hit ctrl+z to stop logs print.

Answer (score 2):

By default forever places all of the files it needs into /$HOME/.forever. If you would like to change that location just set the FOREVER_ROOT environment variable when you are running forever:

```
FOREVER_ROOT=/etc/forever forever start index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Help is your best saviour, there is a logs action that you can call to check logs for all running processes.

```
forever --help
```

Shows the commands

```
logs                Lists log files for all forever processes
logs <script|index> Tails the logs for <script|index>
```

Sample output of the above command, for three processes running. **console.log** output's are stored in these logs.

```
info:    Logs for running Forever processes
data:        script    logfile
data:    [0] server.js /root/.forever/79ao.log
data:    [1] server.js /root/.forever/ZcOk.log
data:    [2] server.js /root/.forever/L30K.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on bryanmac's answer. I'm just saving all logs into one file and then reading it with tail. Simple, but effective way to do this.

`forever -o common.log -e common.log index.js && tail -f common.log`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the log destination specifiers before the filename to run. So

forever -e /path/error.txt -o /path/output.txt start index.js