# How to use forever within a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, forever

I want to run my simple Node server as a background process within my Docker container but when I try and fire it up using `forever` I get the following:

```
fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/.forever/9Spa.log'
```

So I tried just making a folder called `.forever` in my current working directory but then I got pretty much the same error (the `*.log` file has a different name each time I run it, as expected.)

If I run my server without using `forever` it runs fine without any errors. E.g:

```
node server
```

or

```
npm start
```

both work fine, but of course don't run in the background.

I get the same error just running

```
forever list
```

So the issue it clearly with `forever` and not my server code.

`npm list -g` shows that `forever` is installed.

I am using a `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` image in my Docker container.

I'm open to suggestions.

### update

I finally got `forever` to run my making a `.forever` folder in `/home/testuser` and within that a `pids` folder, then running the following:

```
forever start -p /home/testuser/.forever --pidFile /home/testuser/.forever/pids/server.pid server.js
```

According to [the docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

> `-p  PATH` Base path for all forever related files (pid files, etc.)

However that's not quite true. I was forced to specify the absolute path for the `--pidFile`

So, hooray, my server is running as a background process.  However the following still break:

```
forever stop server.js
```

=> 

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:634
  var procs = processes.filter(function (p) {
                        ^
TypeError: Object Error: EACCES, mkdir '/.forever' has no method 'filter'
    at Object.forever.findByScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:634:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:189:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:136:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:89:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:34:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)`

```
forever stop -p /home/bit2bit/.forever server.js
```

same result

```
forever list
```

==>

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:683
    procs.forEach(function (proc) {
          ^
TypeError: Object Error: EACCES, mkdir '/.forever' has no method 'forEach'
    at Object.forever.format (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:683:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:520:28
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:136:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:89:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:34:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)`

So, while I can now start my server, I can't stop it again.

Comment: so it turns out simply ensuring there is a `/.forever` folder and `/.forever/pids` folder (by making them when the `Dockerfile` is building) means I can happily just run `forever start server.js` and `forever list` etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Where does forever store console.log output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021186/where-does-forever-store-console-log-output)

try adding a -o argument to specify where the log will be output to.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that worked - I needed to create my own `logs` folder and specify the absolute path to the logs as follows `forever -l /home/testuser/logs/server.log -o /home/testuser/logs/out.log -e /home/testuser/logs/err.log` for it to work.

Comment: Alas on further investigation all that did was force `forever` to log the same error message into the specified log file. I've since discovered a whole lot more and will update my question with the details.