# Running sails.js with forever.js shows no console output

Tags: sails.js, forever

I am running my sails.js application through forever.js to get the server automatically restarted on file change. I am using Windows for my setup and I can't see any output from sails.js in the console if I use forever.js. I would like to see my console.log outputs, is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021186/where-does-forever-store-console-log-output