# How to get logs of NodeJs application running in forever npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, forever

I was wondering, is there any way I can check out the logs of the my nodejs server when I've forever'd it using `forever start server.js` to look at what's being logged, check any live errors and such.

I looked at their documentation but couldn't find anything related to this. I want to be able to look at the console.

Answer (score 1):

As forever start an application on background it gets hard to access old logs.
If you can use a library for maintaining logs, I will suggest [simple-node-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger) . Using this library you can save all your logs on a file and can access that file any time using:

```
tail -f logsFile.txt
```

Using this command this will keep printing new changes over logsFile.txt as logger keep updating logs.
This will help you to maintain all the logs for you.

Answer (score 0):

First find out where your logs are stored using:

`sudo forever list`

for each process you can see something like this as logfile:

`/root/.forever/_Jht.log`

use 'tail -f' to monitor its changes:

`sudo tail -f /root/.forever/_Jht.log`

You can also set your desired path for log files, see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021251/1119611